# pgsql2shp ERROR: incompatible mixed geometry types in table

Tags: postgis, shapefile, export, pgsql2shp

I have multi-linestring in .shp files and I split the lines with postgis, but that result is only geom column.

It does not works with shape file exporter

> `error: incompatible mixed geometry types in table`

I guess it needs at least gid, shape_leng, polyline_n ...etc columns?

How can I get data able to export .shp file with only geom column?

Comment: You only need an id (or gid if you want to call it that). Just add one to you table. `Alter table mytable add column gid serial`. This will then display correctly in a GIS once you export back to shp. I assume you are using pgsql2shp?

Comment: I use PostGIS shapefile Import/Export Manager (GUI) ..

Comment: I made id column and tried exporting with using st_multi and pgsql2shp in cmd, but it's useless...TT

Comment: I flagged to close this because without sample data it's unclear what the problem is and we can never figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Probably in your table there are more than one type of geometry but, in a shape file, you must have only a type (Line, Polygon or Point).
When you split lines the result could be not only a line but a point ( or multi). Use st_geometrytype(geom) for analyze what you have in your table. If you only need lines, you have just to delete what is not a linestring:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE st_geometrytype(geom) NOT IN ('ST_LineString', 'ST_MultiLineString');
```

After this, export will work. If you want only the geometry column of the shape just delete the .dbf file.